# In Bash, how can I obtain the directory path from the previous command's last argument

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I frequently have to do this. For example:

```
$ vim /etc/pam.d/sudo
$ vim /etc/pam.d/sudo-i
$ cd /etc/pam.d/  # Figure I should just go to the directory
```

Now, is there a way I could obtain the directory of the last argument when it's a file path? What I'm hoping for is something like this:

```
$ vim /etc/pam.d/sudo
$ vim /etc/pam.d/sudo-i
$ cd $dir # <-- something that returns /etc/pam.d in this case
```

I'm asking this cause I recently became aware of the `$_` variable that has become useful. Was wondering if there's some other commandline fu that might come in handy.

Comment: Don't forget you also have tab completion and ESC dot to recall the last argument on the previous command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would use [BillThor's](https://superuser.com/questions/357477/in-bash-how-can-i-obtain-the-directory-path-from-the-previous-commands-last-ar/357487#357487) answer, there is a purely bash answer:

```
$ ls /etc/pam.d/sudo
$ cd !$:h
```

See [History Interaction](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) in the bash manual

Answer (score 2):

The bash history is effectively a text file listing the previously executed commands - it doesn't include any metadata saying what those commands are doing, and what type of parameters are being passed.

So $_ just contains the content after the last space.

I think the answer is no, there isn't any way to do this with bash, you'd probably need a custom shell.

Comment: I was thinking it might be unlikely. Looked through the `man`page and didn't see anything that seemed applicable. Figured I'd ask just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 $(dirname $_)
```

This will give you the directory above whatever was the last argument.  Returns `.` if the there is no directory component.   Also if the argument was something like `/etc/pam.d/`, it will return `/etc`.

Adding the following to your `.profile` file will let you do what you want with the command `cdx`:

```
alias cdx='cd $(dirname $_)'
```

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, this is why stack exchange rocks. Was a shot in the dark. Thanks for the tip!